# Problem With Media Query, it doesn't Work

Tags: html, css

Does Anyone Know Why My Media Queries Doesn't Work ?
I'm Sure That There Is No Any mistake..
The Problem Is, I Want To apply The changes I putted In Extra small (max-width: 575px), And max-width 575px It's Mean That The Screens Smaller Than 575px supposed be like I did up, But What I Find When I Choose From Google Chrome The iPhone 6/7/8 Plus's Screen For Example Or Any Screen, I Don't See The Differences That I putted in Part Of Media Query In Extra Small.
The Strange Thing Is When I Convert Max-width To Min-width With The Same Pixels The Changes apply After 575px and before it Too, How Is That possible If We Know That Min-Width Means That The Start Must be from it, changes Must apply Just From 575px And Up, But I Find That Changes apply Before 575px Too, Hooow?
I Hope You Understand Me, It Took Me 3 Days To Try To Fix It But No Avail.

```
    <!-- Start Header -->    
    
        <header class="header">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Choose Your Plan</h1>
                    <div class="plan">
                        <div>Free Plan Contain 10GB</div>
                        <div>10$ Plan Contain 50GB</div>
                    </div>    
                    <div class="order">Order Now And get Another One For Free</div>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </header>
        
        
        <!-- End Header -->




    /* Start Header */

.header {
    background: url('../Images/business.jpg') no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 500px;
    position: relative
    
}

.header .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(31 8 8 / 70%);
    color: #fff;
}

.header .overlay h1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 50px
}

.header .overlay .plan {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly
}

.header .overlay .plan > div {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px
}

.header .overlay .order {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* End Header */




    /* Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px) */
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .header .overlay .plan {
        display: block
    }
    
    .header .overlay .plan > div {
        width: 30%;
        margin: 0 auto 15px
    }
    
    .order {
        display: none 
    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't you forget the viewport meta tag ?

Answer (score 1):

1. don't forget the  viewport https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp
2. you need to change media rule to "@media only screen and (max-width: 575px)"

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons is not following the same `selector` order when styling. For example, In your code `.header .overlay .order`. You have to use the same `selector` which means styling `.order` this way doesn't work. You can see the difference in the code below.

This one is not working, I mean it works, but not as we're trying to achieve. You **have** to name it in `@media` as you did before.

```css
.text .content .order {
    color: red;
}

@media(max-width: 576px){
    .order {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <div class="content">
        <p class="order">Paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This one works perfectly as we want.

```css
.text .content .order {
    color: red;
}

@media(max-width: 576px){
    .text .content .order {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <div class="content">
        <p class="order">Paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I'm not quite sure that this solves your problem**, but one small change can make your page look different. And don't forget to use `meta tag` also.

```
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```